# Empty Rows where still read when parsing in Papaparse

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I did try to skipEmptyLines = true in papaparse to skip empty row lines but it still pass an empty array what should I do? 40 rows can be only see but the result is 54 rows. This is the file... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kNpUwXShD5gx4W7xoYHk6KZSxjPK99SG/view?usp=drive_link

```
var data = Papa.parse(csv,{
                        header: true,
                        complete: fileReaderComplete,
                        skipEmptyLines: true,
                        
                    });
```